# Python: Append new tuples where not exists in an list

Tags: python

I have three lists. What I want to do is look for 3rd item in TempTree and if this item is not present in the Set then I want to append this third item into STree.

I will be using a `for` loop `TempTree[i]` from `i[2:]`.

Given Data:

```
TempTree = [(3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0), (5.0, 4.0), (3.0, 4.0), (0.0, 7.0), (1.0, 2.0), (7.0, 8.0), (2.0, 3.0), (8.0, 6.0), (0.0, 1.0), (2.0, 5.0), (2.0, 8.0), (6.0, 5.0), (7.0, 6.0)]
Set = [(3.0, 5.0), (5.0, 3.0), (1.0, 7.0), (7.0, 1.0)]
SpanningTree = [(3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0)]
```

My Code:

```
for x in TempTree[2]:
    for y in Set:
        if x != y:
            SpanningTree.append(TempTree[2])
print(SpanningTree)
```

My result:

```
[(3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0), (5.0, 4.0), (5.0, 4.0), (5.0, 4.0), (5.0, 4.0), (5.0, 4.0), (5.0, 4.0), (5.0, 4.0), (5.0, 4.0)]
```

Required Result:

```
[(3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0), (5.0, 4.0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously, you are looking in TempTree[2], i.e you do not check the tuple, but each number inside it (5.0, 4.0). in this case, of course x!=y because x is a float and y is a tuple, hence you get 2 * 4 additions of the tuple. what you should do (did not check it, but it's the main idea):

```
for x in Set:
    if x != TempTree[2]:
            SpanningTree.append(TempTree[2])
            break
print(SpanningTree)
```

also, better use python Set type and not List to prevent multiple occurences.

Comment: I made a small chane - added a break so it won't continue iterating after TempTree[2] is added to the list.

Answer (score 1):

is it what are you looking for?

```
if TempTree[2] not in Set:
    SpanningTree.append(TempTree[2])
```

And in your code on each iteration on Set you check that current element doesn't equal to TempTree[2] and append it every time to SpanningTree(instead of check and append once).